# How to read data from .txt files and reduce it into a Numpy array : Python 3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

So far, here is my code. I am trying to make a Numpy array by reading the data from a file and reducing the size of the data by saving it into an array format so that it is easy for me to plot it on a graph. 
Basically, I have a folder containing 115 files. Each file has around 80K rows of data. The columns are structured like this:

```
    1          2           3       ...     14
Location | Location | Month Average | Month Average
```

When I make this array, it needs to have

- Location
- Min/max value
- Average over the whole year in that specific location
- Total in the specific location.

When I run my code, though, I get a `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`.

```
row = 80000
path = "Folder/files." #the file names have the same root but different years after
array=np.zeros([row,6,115], dtype=np.float) #I am supposed to save as a 3D numpy array. 
np.array([array]).astype(np.float)
for i in range(1900,2015):#the amount of years in the folder
    input_file=open(path+str(i),'r')
    y=0
    for line in input_file:
        values=line.split()
        array[i-1900][y][0] = values[0] #the first number in the array is location
        array[i-1900][y][1] = values[1] #second number is also location 
        array[i-1900][y][2] = np.min(values[2:13])
        array[i-1900][y][3] = np.max(values[2:13])
        array[i-1900][y][4] = np.mean(values[2:13])
        array[i-1900][y][5] = np.sum(values[2:13])
    y+=1
a= array
np.save('array.npy', a)
print (a)
```

Comment: What's the point of the `y` variable? It seems to always have the same value as `i-1900`.

Comment: Also, can you give us the full traceback? Specifically, which line does it error on?

Comment: i am not so sure what the point of Y is. my instructor said to keep that there. Also the error seems to me from one of the site packages.
"Anacoda3\lib\site-pacjages\umpy\core\_methods/py", line 29, in_amin
returen umr_minimum(a,axis,None, out, keepdims) TypeError:...."